# Plotting mathematical function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

i'm trying to write function called **plotting** which takes i/p parameters Z, p and q and plots the function

```
f(y) = det(Z − yI) on the interval [p, q]
```

(Note: I is the identity matrix.) det() is the determinant.

For finding det(), `numpy.linalg.det()` can be used
and for indentity matrix , `np.matlib.identity(n)`

Is there a way to write such functions in python? and plot them?

```
import numpy as np

def f(y):
    I2 = np.matlib.identity(y)
    x = Z-yI2
    numpy.linalg.det(x)
    ....
```

Is what i am tryin correct? any alternative?

Comment: So, what values does the variables `Z`, `p`, `q`, `y` take?

Comment: @kmario23 any integer values , can be specified as variable., for eg, 1,2,3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following implementation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(y, Z):  
    n, m = Z.shape
    assert(n==m)
    I = np.identity(n)
    x = Z-y*I
    return np.linalg.det(x)

Z = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
p = -15
q = 15
y = np.linspace(p, q)
w = np.zeros(y.shape)

for i in range(len(y)):
    w[i] = f(y[i], Z)

plt.plot(y, w)
plt.show()
```

[image]